# There is no KDE compatibility plugin in CCSM in focal

Tags: compiz, ccsm

I use `mate-desktop` and `mate-panel` with `dockbarx plugin`. It needs `KDE compatibility plugin` to enable window preview in minimized state, but it doesn't exist in `CCSM`. I checked out the repositories, I haven't come across such a plugin in the Ubuntu.
How can I install it?

**EDIT:**

Though it's irrelevant I post how I installed `dockbarx` upon request from [N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert)

My Ubuntu version is 20.04.1
I installed compiz from Ubuntu repositories.
I installed `dockbarx` from https://github.com/M7S/dockbarx/tree/pygi-python3
I grabbed zip package from that branch extracted it and edited the hardcoded paths in the files in `mate-panel applet`

path in file `org.mate.panel.applet.DockbarXAppletFactory.service` to:

```
 Exec=/usr/local/lib/mate-panel/dockbarx_mate_applet
```

path in file `org.mate.panel.DockbarX.mate-panel-applet` to:

```
 Location=/usr/local/lib/mate-panel/dockbarx_mate_applet
```

I installed dependencies such as

```
  sudo apt install gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 python3-cairo python3-dbus python3-distutils python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-pil python3-polib python3-xdg python3-xlib python3-polib
```

Then I installed `dockbarx` within directory via

```
  sudo ./setup.py install
```

Added it to `mate-applet` directory

```
  sudo cp /usr/local/share/mate-panel/applets/org.mate.panel.DockbarX.mate-panel-applet /usr/share/mate-panel/applets/
```

Finally I modified the path in file `/usr/share/mate-panel/applets/org.mate.panel.DockbarX.mate-panel-applet` to:

```
  Location=/usr/local/share/mate-panel/applets/org.mate.panel.DockbarX.mate-panel-applet
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How did you installed Compiz? Where have you got `dockbarx`?

Comment: @N0rbert I updated my question.

Comment: I have not used this application before, but [README](https://github.com/M7S/dockbarx/blob/master/README.md) mentions a PPA with packages [for focal](https://launchpad.net/~xuzhen666/+archive/ubuntu/dockbarx/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=focal) with interesting package named *dockbarx-mate-panel-applet*. It may work better.

Comment: @N0rbert Thank you for responding. `dockbarx` works well, I have no problem with it. As it is stated in REDME file `NOTE! To use previews with Compiz you need to activate KDE Compability in compiz settings manager and under KDE Compability check "Support Plasma Thumbnails". You can not use previews with other window manager than Compiz and Kwin.`, it requires `KDE Compability plugin` in CCSM. There are `Gnome compatibility` and `mate compatibility` plugins in CCSM, but it's missing  `KDE Compability plugin`. It existed in older distros, I wonder if it's dropped by compiz developers.

Comment: I see, now investigating the issue. Stay tuned :)

Comment: Just curious - do you have thumbnails with for normal (not-minimized) windows? On my UM 20.04 LTS system I see such thumbnails. The thumbnails for minimized windows are [not shown](https://github.com/M7S/dockbarx/issues/3#issuecomment-634278592), this is right.

Comment: @N0rbert yes, window preview is shown for windows on desktop. I also tried `compiz`s own thumbnail preview plugin with `workarounds` plugin. `workarounds` plugin provides preview for minimized windows but `thumbnail preview plugin` doesn't work well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111419/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-kenn).

Comment: Done, see below updated answer. Then we can cleanup the comments to make Q&A clear.

Answer (score 2):

### Analysis

This "KDE Compatibility" option was last available in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I'm not sure were *dockbarx* operational here or not.

Then this option was removed [at 2019-02-05](https://git.launchpad.net/compiz/commit/?id=a55d3fb3fc6cdeeae69baffe0ebb9ca84679a692).

It is very hard to revert this diff as patch. Many things were changed.

### Workaround

The most interesting moment here is that we do not need to have KDE Compatibility in the system. The internals are changed. Details are below.

Complete reproducible method to get *dockbarx* installed with MATE applet previews of minimized windows is presented below.

At first we need to install Compiz into the Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS system by:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-core compiz-mate compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-default
```

Then launch MATE Tweak by `mate-tweak`, select *Windows* tab, in *Window manager* switch *Select window manager* to *Compiz (Advanced GPU accelerated desktop effects)*.

Then add the PPA with the application:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xuzhen666/dockbarx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dockbarx-mate-panel-applet
```

Then install CompizConfig Settings Manager by

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Launch CompizConfig Settings Manager, enable *Workarounds* and enable the *Keep previews of minimized windows* (as stated in the newest [source code](https://github.com/M7S/dockbarx/blob/bf73c94710c630be10d14320fef92df7cd867259/po/dockbarx.pot#L451)).

Then add Dockbarx to the MATE Panel, enter to its *Preferences* and ensure that in *Window List* → *Previews* you have checked the *Show previews of minimized windows*.

Logout and login back.

And finally enjoy the obtained result:

> [image: DockbarX with preview of minimized window]

Note: sometimes it shows some extra gray rectangle below the actual thumbnail, but it is functional.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not what I want. I already knew that trick which I mentioned in comments. It doesn't work well. What I want is to use preview of `dockbarx`s own plugin. Check out `dbx_preference` > `window list` then check ticks in `previews` items.